# Canonical projection is open - Projective Space

Tags: general-topology, projective-space, quotient-spaces, open-map

> Show that canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^{n}$ is open.

I tried to prove it, but I have a hard time pulling the aberts. I search the internet but only find the projection using the sphere $\pi:\mathbb{S}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^{n}$.

Comment: You wrote "$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash$ {0}" Then someone corrected that so that it said "$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash \{0\}$". Then I corrected that further so it said "$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}.$ So note proper MathJax usage.

Comment: "pulling the aberts"  means "manipulating the open sets" ?

Comment: @freegoodman In portuguese, "open set" translates as "conjunto aberto". I'd guess OP is not used to certain math terms in English.

Comment: I've never seen the word "abert" before and Google isn't helping with that.

Comment: Portuguese "aberto" = Spanish "abierto" = English "open".

Comment: Yes @freegoodman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\R{\mathbb R}$
$\def\Rnp{\mathbb R^{n+1}}$
Let $U \in \Rnp$ open.  We need to show that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is open. But $$\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = \{r x : r \in \R \setminus \{0\}, x \in U\} = \bigcup_{r\in \R \setminus \{0\}} r U,$$
which is a union of open sets, hence open.